# Showing that a certain "norm-like" function fails to satisfy triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, combinatorics, measure-theory

For any symmetric measurable function $h: I \times I \to \mathbb{R}$, define $$|h| =\sqrt[6]{\int h(x,y)h(x,y')h(x',y)h(x',y')h(x,x')h(y,y') d\mu(x,y,x',y')} $$ where $\mu$ denotes the Lebesgue measure and the integral is assumed to exist.

> Does $|\cdot|$ satisfy sub-additivity  $$|h + h'| \leq |h| +
>  |h'|   $$ or not?

I think we can construct a counter-example, but I'm not sure it's correct.

Let $I$ denote the unit interval. Define $f: I \times I \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$f(x,y)  = \begin{cases} 0 & x \in [0, \frac{1}{2}], \ y \in [0, \frac{1}{2}] \\  
0 & x \notin [0, \frac{1}{2}], \ y \notin [0, \frac{1}{2}] \\
1 & x \in [0, \frac{1}{2}], \ y \notin [0, \frac{1}{2}]
\\
1 & x \notin [0, \frac{1}{2}], \ y \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]
  \end{cases}    $$

Also, define $g: I \times I \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$g(x,y)  = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in [0, \frac{1}{2}], \ y \in [0, \frac{1}{2}] \\  
1 & x \notin [0, \frac{1}{2}], \ y \notin [0, \frac{1}{2}] \\
0 & x \in [0, \frac{1}{2}], \ y \notin [0, \frac{1}{2}]
\\
0 & x \notin [0, \frac{1}{2}], \ y \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]
  \end{cases}    .$$

Then $|f +g|=\sqrt[6]{1}=1$ but $|f| =|g|  = \sqrt[6]{\frac{1}{8}}$.

> My concern is that I have messed up my computation. Does $|\cdot|$ actually satisfy sub-additivity? If not, then what is a correct counter-example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

- For $h=f+g,$ since $(f+g) \equiv 1$ the integrand is $1$ and $|h| = 1$, i.e. you are correct.
- For $h=g,$ the integrand is $1$ if, out of the four variables, any pair of variables belong to the same half of $I$.  This of course means all four must belong in the same half. So the integral $= 1/8, |g| = \sqrt[6]{1/8},$ i.e. you are correct.
- For $h=f,$ the integrand is $1$ if, out of the four variables, any pair of variables belong to different halves of $I$.  This is... actually impossible.  If $x,y$ belong to different halves and $x',y$ belong to different halves, then $x,x'$ belong to the same half.  So the integrand $\equiv 0$ and $|f| = 0,$ i.e. you made a mistake.
- Nevertheless, it is true that $|f+g| = 1 > |f| + |g| = \sqrt[6]{1/8}$

Comment: Please be more careful of typos -- I'm sure you mean $h$ not $f$ inside the integral (in your comment).  :)  Anyway, yeah for that new $|.|$ I agree that $|f| = \sqrt[4]{1/8} \approx 0.59$.

Comment: Wait, so what is the problem?  With the new $|.|$ (defined using $4$th root) we have $|f|=|g| \approx 0.59$ so $|f|+|g| > |f+g| = 1$.

Comment: You're right, there is no problem. I made a silly mistake.